# Moving files in a directory except file with current date

Tags: php, bash, shell, backup, sh

I wish to move  files contained in a directory but I do not wish to move the file with the current date. eg. Current date is February 12, 2014 translates to 20140212

When I list files in source directory: `/source`

```
record_20140209
record_20140210
record_20140211
record_20140212
```

I wish to move to a target directory :/ target
all files except the file with current date which is record_20140212.
So in the above list, the ones below should be moved to /target directory.

```
record_20140209
record_20140210
record_20140211
```

Any ideas would be of great help. I wish to write the script using bash script but php will also be fine. My OS is Centos 5.Let me know if you have questions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To move all the files except current date you can do:

```
cd /source
dt=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
for f in record_*; do
    [[ "$f" != *"$dt" ]] && mv "$f" /target
done
```

Comment: +1 Nice. I might be tempted to go for "for f in record_*" to be on the safe side in case OP has other stuff in there.

Comment: Sure thing, if OP has other files too then `record_*` is safer (edited in my answer).